# Implementing a WakefulIntentService

Tags: android, wakelock

I am trying to implement a WakefulIntentService using the CommonsWare example. I need to pass a Location to the subclass of the WakefulIntentService, but I haven't been able to do that.

I call sendWakefulWork using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, WakefulIntentService.class);
i.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION, location);
WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, i);
```

On WakefulIntentService class I have the following method:

```
public static void sendWakefulWork(Context context, Intent i) {
    getLock(context).acquire();
    i.setClass(context, ProtocolController.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

And finally, ProtocolController class:

```
public class ProtocolController extends WakefulIntentService {

    public ProtocolController() {
        super(ProtocolController.class.getSimpleName());
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "starting Protocol");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Doing wakeful work");
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you did not ask a question here. Second, support for `WakefulIntentService`, as is indicated on the project's home page, is via the [cw-android Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass a Location object in the way you are trying. I would use putExtra to pass the individual values you need such as the latitude and longitude, timestamp etc... Use putExtra to pass your basic values likes strings, floats, ints, booleans etc...

Comment: Yes, it can be done: you can pass it as an object and it does work fine.